# Mongoose not working with double quotes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB to save data for app's users :

```
mongoose.connect(dBAddress, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('WARNING: Cannot connect to mongoDB at: ' + dBAddress);
    } else {
        dBConnected = true;
        console.log('Connected to mongoDB at: ' + dBAddress);
    }
});
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    'userName': String,
    'password': String,
    'userId': String,
    'lastModificationTime': {type: String, default: Common.getCurrentFormanttedTime()},
    'createdTime': {type: String, default: Common.getCurrentFormanttedTime()}
});
User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

And I insert data as :

```
        var newUser = {
            'userName': newUserInfo.userName,
            'password': newUserInfo.password,
            'userId': newUserId,
            'lastModificationTime': Common.getCurrentFormanttedTime(),
            'createdTime': Common.getCurrentFormanttedTime()
        };
        var user = new User(newUser);
        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log('There is a problem saving the user info');
            } else {
                console.log('A new user saved: ');
                console.log(newUser);
            }
        });
```

Now I want to check if the there's another document with the same value for `userName` field or not:

```
var keyValueExists = function(key, value) {
    var exists = false;
    User.count({key: value}, function(err, count) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log('Problem with `.find` function');
        } else {
            console.log('count: ' + count);
            exists = (count !== 0);
        }
    });
    return exists;
};
```

Now the problem is that this last function never returns `true` ! 
For example let's assume that we have this document in our collection :

```
{
"userName": "user1"
}
```

(Note: this is the result of running the mongo shell command : `db.users.find()`)

When we call this function with these parameters : `keyValueExists('userName','user1')` it returns false , but when instead of `'userName'` I hardcode `userName` (without quotes) it works !

Why does this happen ? and how can I get rid of this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your `keyValueExists` function to this:

```
var keyValueExists = function(key, value, callback) {
    var exists = false;
    var query = {}; query[key] = value;

    User.count(query, function(err, count) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log('Problem with `.find` function');
        } else {
            console.log('count: ' + count);
            exists = (count !== 0);
        }

        callback(err, exists);
    });
};

keyValueExists('userName','user1', function (err, isExists) {
    // your logic
});
```

In your code the request to MongoDB is `{key: 'user1'}` instead `{userName: 'user1'}` since object notation stringifies

Comment: Would have been nice if you explained that otherwise it would be sent as `{ "key": "user1"}` since object notation stringifies. But kudos for being basically correct.

Comment: Another problem with this code is that it has asynchronous calls (`count`) which makes it return `false` right away without considering the result back from mongoDB.